# Failed to instantiate module in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory

UserServices.js

```
angular.module('UserService', ['ngResource']).factory('UserFactory', ['$http', function() {

return {
    // call to get all nerds
    get : function() {
        return $http.get('/api/User');
    },

    // call to POST and create a new geek
    create : function(userData) {
        return $http.post('/api/User', userData);
    },


    // call to DELETE a geek
    delete : function(id) {
        return $http.delete('/api/User/' + id);
    }
}

}]);
```

UserCtrl.js

```
angular.module('UserCtrl', ['UserFactory']).controller('UserController',    
['$scope','UserFactory',  function($scope, UserFactory) {

$scope.insert = function(){
$scope.fromfactory = UserFactory.create($scope.user);
}

}]);
```

Comment: Believe you're missing the $http injection in your factory function/definition

Answer (score 1):

In UserCtrl, you need to retrieve the module, not redefine it:

**UserCtrl**

```
 angular.module('UserService').controller('UserController'...);
```

Here is a proper structure of a module:

**JS**

```
var app = angular('app', ['ngResource']);
app.factory('UserFactory', function() { ... });
app.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope) {...});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app='app'>
 ...
</body>
```